# FFmpeg concat with absolute path

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I try to concatenate two videos using ffmpeg I use that wrapper: [wrapper](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java).
According docs I use this commands :

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i concat:"intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

After two command I got two files:

`/storage/emulated/0/recorder/test1_convert.ts` `/storage/emulated/0/recorder/test2_convert.ts`

But when I execute the third command I got failure: log message: `concat:"/storage/emulated/0/recorder/test1_convert.ts|/storage/emulated/0/recorder/test2_convert.ts": No such file or directory`

I suppose something wrong with syntax absolute path. This is full my third command:

[image]

Comment: Can you read this file by usual hava commands?

Comment: Actually the documentation has another pair of double quotes around input, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate. HTH.

Comment: As with many issues involving `ffmpeg` usage on Android it is probably a quoting issue. Try it without the double quotes in the concat line.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you were right, it was double quotes in the contact line issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the double-quotes in the concat line.

I am not an Android user but quoting seems to be a typical problem on Android when using `ffmpeg`.